# How do i call a method from a singleton service to run throughout the application lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

I have implemented a Kafka event bus as a singleton service in Net Core. The service itself is configured with Autofac in Startup.cs. The service has a `Listen()` method:

```
public void Listen()
{
    using(var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(_config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
    {
        consumer.Subscribe(new string[] { "business-write-topic" });

        consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} Offset: {msg.Offset} {msg.Value}");
            consumer.CommitAsync(msg);
        };

        while (true)
        {
            consumer.Poll(100);
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that in order for this method to constantly listen for messages during the lifetime of the application, i have to call it in Program.cs from the web host by somehow getting the ServiceProvider associated with the host, then retrieving an instance of the service, and calling the method.

I have configured my Program.cs from the default Net Core 2.1 template to the following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHost(args);
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost CreateWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Beyond having the host available so i can somehow access the services, i don't know where to go from here. I have searched for similar questions and read around in the official docs but i can't seem to figure out how to access the service so that i can call the `Listen()` method.

Is this the "go-to" way of accomplishing my goal? If so, how do i proceed? And if not - that is - if this kind of task is commonly accomplished in another way, how do i go about it?

Comment: Can you please provide your startup code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

The answer below is still perfectly valid. There is a base-class called `BackgroundService` provided by Microsoft that can be used where you only need to implement `ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)` rather than the whole interface of `IHostedService`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L24). For that you will need to install the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`.

**Previous and still valid answer:**
I would suggest to use [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1). IHostedService implementations are registered as singletons and they run the whole time until the server shuts down.

Create this base class

```
public abstract class HostedService : IHostedService
{
    private Task executingTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

        this.executingTask = this.ExecuteAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        return this.executingTask.IsCompleted ? this.executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (this.executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        await Task.WhenAny(this.executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
    }

    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Then create the consumer-host

```
public class ConsumerHost : HostedService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(_config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
            consumer.Subscribe(new string[] {"business-write-topic"});

            consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} Offset: {msg.Offset} {msg.Value}");
                consumer.CommitAsync(msg);
            };

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) // will make sure to stop if the application is being shut down!
            {
                consumer.Poll(100);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your startup-class in the ConfigureService method add the singleton

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ConsumerHost>();
}
```

This service will now kick in when the webhost finished building and stop when you shutdown the server. No need to manually trigger it, let the webhost do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a final question - i see that HostedService  is a customized version of the BackgroundService base class available in Net Core 2.1. What are the advantages of using HostedService instead of deriving from the BackgroundService provided by the framework?

Comment: I actually didn't know there is a baseclass and it hasn't been there when I first worked with IHostedService. From what I saw in the sourcecode iit is very much the same accept for one thing. They implemented IDisposable which I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) is what you need.

```
public class ListnerBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ListnerService service;

    public ListnerBackgroundService(ListnerService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        service.Listen();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And register it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ListnerBackgroundService>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't respect the fact that the server shuts down and will therefore not clean up properly.