# .NET Core Hosted services timeout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I've started using .NET Core Hosted services to handle some pub/sub functionality. I plan to use cancellation tokens to shut the services down. And I wonder whether there is some timeout for them? I want the service to run forever if it has not been explicitly stopped.

Appreciate your help.

```
        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var redisPubSub = new RedisPubSubServer(ClientsManager, Constants.RedisChannel)
                {
                    OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Received '{msg}' from channel '{channel}'");
                        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(msg);                          
                            _hubContext.Clients.User(message.UserId.ToString()).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message, cancellationToken);
                    },
                    OnUnSubscribe = (message) =>
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"OnUnSubscribe returns {message}");
                    },
                    OnError = (exception) =>
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"OnError returns {exception}");
                    },
                    OnStart = () =>
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"OnStart has been fired.");
                    },
                    OnStop = () =>
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"OnStop has been fired");
                    }
                };

                redisPubSub.Start();
                Trace.WriteLine($"OnStop has been fired {redisPubSub.WaitBeforeNextRestart}  {redisPubSub.HeartbeatTimeout}  {redisPubSub.HeartbeatInterval}");
            }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: Please do it as I described in my linked answer. You are running this now in another background-task. Just have a while-loop after your code that checks for cancellation-token being cancelled and put a delay in there.

Comment: @alsami, thank you. Do you know why it does not stop in the case with Task.Factory.StartNew ?

Comment: Each task you create and run, runs in the thread-pool. Is therefore not stopped with the hosted-service.

https://owlcation.com/stem/C-ThreadPool-and-its-Task-Queue-Example

Answer (score 0):

If you check out my accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616000/how-do-i-call-a-method-from-a-singleton-service-to-run-throughout-the-applicatio/51616620#51616620), and your hostedservice kinda looks like that, you can just do the following within the while-loop contained in the `ExecuteAsync` method.

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationToken);
```

The method must be marked as async of course.

Comment: And if I register it as services.AddHostedService<ClientHostedService>();
then what?

Comment: Well I don't know why they did that, but that extension method is not registering the hosted-service as a singleton. It registers the hosted service as transient.

    public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services) where THostedService : class, IHostedService
    {
      return services.AddTransient<IHostedService, THostedService>();
    }

Comment: So from your main answer I see that you suggest making Task.Delay, however, when I do not do this in my ExecuteAsync the service is not being shut down - it continues handling messages. My assumption is that it does not stop when ExecuteAsync finished working. But I am not sure whether it stops after some timeout. I run it for 10 minutes approximately - it did not stop.

Comment: Well it does stop, you have to pass the cancellationtoken and you have to await it. It will stop when you shut down the server, but only then.

Comment: @alsami the service acts as a singleton. It's managed, started, stopped by the [HostedServiceExecutor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.hostedserviceexecutor?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class, which is a singleton

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Why mark it as transient in the first place then? Is there some explanation for that?

Comment: I know it is kind of weird but the service does not stop even if I do not await the token.

Comment: Please provide Startup code and HostedService code in your question.

Comment: I need to see the implementation, not the abstraction. Please also edit your question instead of adding answers.

Comment: @alsami, added the implementation